# How to automate testing of html5 media elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, gruntjs, phantomjs

I am currently using nodejs, grunt and phantomjs to automate testing of javascript. But I recently noticed that phantomjs does not support html5 media elements (video, audio, track). I was wondering if anybody knows a good way to solve this? Or have you skipped automation of the tests using the html5 media elements?

Regards,
John

Comment: What sort of non-solutions did you find when you googled for this information? That would be useful to possible answerers to know what sort of things are not applicable to your case.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Just used video and audio elements and I'm getting undefined errors when testing code that uses .play() or .pause() methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PhantomJS does not support media elements because it will require a variety of different codecs implementations ([see their wiki](http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html)).